# Add CHECK constraint with column from another table

Tags: postgresql, constraints, check-constraints

I have two tables:

> schedules:
>
> - id **INT**
> - daily_schedule_id **INT**
> - start **TIMESTAMP**
> - finish **TIMESTAMP**
>
> ---
>
> daily_schedules:
>
> - id **INT**
> - date **DATE**

I'd like to add a constraint to `schedules.start` and `schedules.finish` which checks the value of `daily_schedules.date`. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Something along these lines:

```
ALTER TABLE schedules 
   ADD CONSTRAINT schedules_date_range_check CHECK (start = daily_schedules.date AND finish = daily_schedules.date)
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a (second) foreign key - and if you already have one, then why duplicate the information? If the values should always be the same, you only need it one table.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name to be more specific.. table one has "start" and "finish" datetime columns. table two has a "date". and i want to make sure that "start" and "finish" fall under the same date as table two's date column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name updated the columns. sorry for the confusion

Comment: If `daily_schedules` does not have any other columns, I would completely remove that table. Then add a `boolean` column `is_daily_schedule` to `schedules` and a check constraint that ensures that `start = finish` if `is_daily_schedule = true`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i would agree with you on that but what we're trying to achieve is add the restriction in this given circumstance... without having to remove the table/column..

Comment: But the _correct_ solution is to not have the `daily_schedule` table to begin with

Comment: How would you handle overnight schedules?

Answer (score 1):

While there are ways to do that technically, it is not supported and a bad idea, as it may cause dumps that cannot be restored.

It is always a good idea to avoid redundancy in databases, so I recommend that you store `start` and `finish` in `schedules` with the data type `time`, which is understood relative to the `date` of the related `daily_schedules`.

Just add the `time` and the `date`, and voila, you got a `timestamp`.

Comment: I didn't propose changing `daily_schedules`, only `schedules`. But with a proper table design, explicit consistency checks often become unnecessary, because consistency is guaranteed by default. What is the problem you see with my proposed change?

Comment: `start` and `finish` already have timestamps.. sorry for not being clear about this. in the application layer, we have a validation which ensures that the date is correct before creating/updating the schedule times. but there have been instances where this has been bypassed. we've written tests for this scenario and none seem to fail... which made us consider looking into constraints for this..

Comment: On the application layer you can still have timestamps - just add the `time` with the `date` from the other table and present that to the user. Sure, this requires some changes in your database access layer, but that change should be pretty localized, and you get a cleaner data model.

Comment: How would we handle the date for overnight schedules?

Comment: That wouldn't work with my idea. From your question I assumed that `schedules.start` and `schedules.finish` have to be on `daily_schedules.date`.

Comment: Is using the constraint still a bad option for us given the circumstances?

Comment: Yes. Do not try to use a check constraint for that, use a trigger.